# creating json array out of user input using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm new to react and have a small requirement to display the user input form data to json array in UI. Here is the form looks like:

```
input:
     field1:12
     field2:12
input:
      field1:12
      field2:12
outut:
      field1:12
      field2:12
outut:
      field1:12
      field2:12
```

I have already implemented add/remove functionality to clone input and output section in the form.
My end goal is to display the input & output form data as below json format:

```
{
  "input": [
    {
     field1:12,field2:12
    },
   {
     field1:12,field2:12
    }
  ],
  "output": [
    {
     field1:12,field2:12
    },
   {
     field1:12,field2:12
    }
  ]
}
```

IN my form component class below code is being used to render :

```
render() {
    var fieldsArray = [];
    return (
     <div>  
      <div id="input_section">
        <table><tr><td><h3>Input</h3></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <li><label> field1 : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="id" onChange={this.onInputChange} /></li>
            <li><label> field2 : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="inputType"  onChange={this.onInputChange} /></li>   
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button onClick={this.addElement}>+</button>
          <button onClick={this.removeElement}>-</button>
        </div>

          <div id="output_section">
          <table><tr><td><h3>Output</h3></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <li><label> field1 : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="id" onChange={this.onOutputChange} /></li>
            <li><label> field2 : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="outputType" onChange={this.onOutputChange}/></li>
           <br/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          <button onClick={this.addElement}>+</button>
          <button onClick={this.removeElement}>-</button>
          </div>
          <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button onClick={this.onSubmitForm}>Preview</button>
            </td>
          </tr></table>
      </div>
    );
```

to initialize the state i have below code:

```
  this.state = {
      input: {},
      output:{}
     };
```

In my parent component , i set the form data to state and finally using below code i render the same:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input:{},
      transform:{},
      output:{}
    };

    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    }
    submitForm(values) {
      this.setState({ values }) 
    }

  render() {
    const test = this.state.values;
    let obj = Object.assign({}, test );  // creates a brand new object
    //forming the json array in desired format
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>obj[key]=[obj[key]]);
   
    return (
      <div>
        <FormDemo1
          onFormSubmit={this.submitForm}/>
        <div>
          <JSONPretty id="json-pretty" data={obj}></JSONPretty>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me on iterating the each section input/output and store the same into my json array as per above json format.

Comment: is there any info , i need to share to get the suggestions for my question? React experts may help me here

Comment: Did you ever solve this?